# Returning an rvalue reference that is passed to a function as an argument

Tags: c++, function, reference, stack, rvalue

I want to understand whether I can safely return an rvalue reference that is passed as an argument to a function and it doesn't get destroyed with the stack unwinding.

```
struct Struct { int m; };

Struct& f(Struct&& rvalue)
{ 
    std::cout << &rvalue << '\n';
    return rvalue;
}

void main()
{
    Struct& lvalue1 = f(Struct{ 1 });
    std::cout << &lvalue1 << '\n';
    Struct& lvalue2 = f(Struct{ 2 });
    std::cout << &lvalue2 << '\n';

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Output:

```
00A3F844
00A3F844
00A3F838
00A3F838
```

This code produces different addresses for the rvalues. Does that mean that actual constructing of Struct objects happens before a function call and I can safely do this kind of things?

Comment: Note that in C++ the `main` function is required to have the return type `int`.

Comment: @François Andrieux Is that from the standard? As far as I know Windows doesn't use the return value from the main.

Comment: [It is required by the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.main#2). Platforms can provide additional overloads, but even those need to have the return type `int`.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can safely do this kind of things?

No. `Struct{ 1 }` and `Struct{ 2 }` construct [temporary objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) which get destroyed after the full expression. That means the reference `lvalue1` and `lvalue2` are always dangled. Dereference on them leads to undefined behavior.

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created

Comment: Could you safely do `Struct&& f(Struct&& rvalue) { return std::move(rvalue); }` and then bind the return value to an rvalue reference again, i.e., `Struct&& doesThisWork = f(Struct{1});`? I think it should, but unsure...

Comment: I wonder why the first struct doesn't get overridden by the second with the stack unwinding then. I can access m members and get `1` and `2` respectively after the f calls.

Comment: @lubgr No - it's still binding to a temporary that will be destroyed.

Comment: @OleksijPlotnyc'kyj Undefined Behaviour is Undefined - no point reasoning about it.

Comment: @lubgr No. For [reference initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary), *In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to which the temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime.*.

Comment: @songyuanyao "as the last step in evaluating the full-expression" does it mean right after assigning the address of return value to the lvalue reference in this case?

Comment: @OleksijPlotnyc'kyj Yes, at the poinit of the `;`.